# Init function isn't calling when Reflux.createStore

Tags: mocking, jestjs, refluxjs

I have mocked store

```
var action = Reflux.createAction('action');
var mockFn = jest.genMockFn();

var store = Reflux.createStore({
    init: function () {
        console.log("INIT MOCK");
        this.listenTo(action, this.onAction);
    },
    onAction: function () {
        mockFn();
    }
});

export default store;
```

and when component try to listen the store

```
componentDidMount = () => {

  ...

  const deregStoreListener = ConceptStore.listen(
    ({nodes,centroids}) => {
      ...
    }
  )
}
```

it throw error

> TypeError: _index2.default.listen is not a function

The strange behavior is that **init** function wasn't called. So Reflux.createStore didn't created store properly. Why?

Comment: Dont forget to import the store file. i think the store is not called. i was facing the same problem once. and its that my store file is never called. so i have imported it in my staring component and it was working.